# onload event from iframe that is dynamically generated via ajax is not firing in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I have this ajax form that send filter fields:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(Model.Action, Model.Controller, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "onBegin", OnSuccess = "onSuccess", OnComplete = "onComplete" }, new { id = "formTemplate" }))
```

When we submit this form it returns a partial view:

//PARTIAL VIEW RETURNED

```
 @model PDFModel

    <iframe id="rptIframe" frameborder="0" src="@Url.Action(Model.Action, Model.Controller, new { someItemID= Model.SomeItemID, someItemID2= Model.SomeItemID2 })#zoom=70"></iframe>
```

//

Here is my onSucess event:

```
function onSuccess(result)
{
   $("#rptContainer").html(result);
}
```

When i insert it to html page, it fires the Url.Action from iframe's src...
this action returns a crystal report as PDF that is rendered below the form, this works perfectly in Chrome.

My problem is that i have a loading gif running when the request is working, i hide it  using the onload event from iframe, but onload event is not firing in IE, how can i workaround this?.

I already tried things like:

```
document.getElementById('frameRelatorio').setAttribute('onload', 'iframeLoad();');
```

and

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('frameRelatorio');

    if (iframe.attachEvent) {
        iframe.attachEvent('onload', iframeLoad);
    }
    else {
        iframe.onload = iframeLoad;
    }
```

and

```
onload="return someFunction();"   //at the iframe
```

and many others solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped to search how to make onload work in IE, and start to search how to detect if iframe is fully loaded and then found this page:

http://community.sitepoint.com/t/determining-when-an-iframe-is-fully-loaded/4724/18

So i adapted to my problem and it work as expected

```
function onSuccess(result)
{
   $("#rptContainer").html(result);

      if ($.browser.msie) {
          var myiframe = document.getElementById('frameRelatorio');
          myiframe.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (myiframe.readyState == 'complete') {
                    iframeLoad();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I kept the onload attribute in iframe's definition so it can work in Chrome, and then inside onSuccess event use the onreadystatechange event, so IE can detect and work as i want.